# How change Intelij running port in static web project?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm working on 2 projects with Intellij and one on Webstorm. All those three are using same port http://localhost:63343. When I changed port it not worked.
I need change ports. There are files with same names and it is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

In WebStorm 8 press Alt+F7

> File-->Settings

Category:

> IDE Settings -> Debugger -> JavaScript

Change "`Built in server port`"